# Change pictures in grid Bootstrap on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with my grid.I have grid(Bootstrap) in this grid are some pictures,a i want when someone when mouseover on someone picture ,picture will change with other.I try some function but is not work.
This is my grid:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">

            <img src="karta.png"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="karta.png"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="karta.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And i want to change this pictures in grid on `mouseover` with:

```
<div id="page_effect" style="display:none;">


<img src="karta1.png"/>


<img src="karta1.png"/>


<img src="karta1.png"/>

 </div>
```

I try something like this but is not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".col-sm-4").mouseleave(function(){
        $("page_effect").attr()('src', 'karta1.png');
    });

    $(".col-sm-4").mouseover(function(){
        $("page_effect").attr("('src', 'karta1.png')");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".col-sm-4").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find("img").attr('src', 'karta1.png');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find("img").attr('src', 'karta.png');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/8xbgmsj7/)

Learn more about `attr()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: @BlueMaster I'm glad for you! Can you accept the answer then :)